# Android uninstalled app records

Tags: android, uninstallation, records

I want get the records of the deleted apps.Can this be realized?Some apps may have deleted now,I want to get the records.I want know the API.
Thanks very much!

Comment: Not sure if there is an API, but all the apps you download from PlayStore are listed under 'My Apps & Games --> All'

Comment: I want get the reords by my App,also in China there many "PlayStores" ,all your apps may come from different ways.

Answer (score 0):

Use Fabric or any app analytics. Basically those are used for monitoring live log of app crash and reporting, but you can dig dipper and find a very detailed result like active user, new installs, unistall etc. give it a try. Using those are very simple too

[fabric](https://fabric.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Use CleverTap for analytics and engagement They track your uninstalls on a daily basis. If you want to track your uninstalls yourself then check out the detailed explanation here.
https://clevertap.com/blog/track-app-uninstalls-effectively/